# How to convert the string to TimeHour24?

Tags: time, type-conversion, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have to populate by code a Table Field.
The table filed having a *EDT* **TimeHour24**.
[image: Field Timehour24]

My String is like `"05:30:15"` 
I have to convert the string to EDT `TimeHour24`.

I used the function `str2time` but it is not useful.

How can I import and fill the field?

Thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should try again with `str2time`
For a test I just created a simple table with one field of the EDT `TimeHour24` and filled it with the job below.
See the screenshot with the desired result as far as I understood the problem

```
static void TimeTest(Args _args)
{
    TimeTest tb;
    ;

    tb.TimeHour24 = str2time("05:30:15");
    tb.write();
}
```

[image: Screenshot of working example]

I could imagine that you dumped the converted result to the infolog and saw a large integer and therefore thought it is not correct.
The result of the conversion is the time in seconds and is how it is internally stored in the database behind the scenes.
AX just displays the value in a human-readable way.

Comment: Hi @DAXaholic, really thanks! Have a reason, work well. I appreace your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere the DateTimeUtil class. It work with a time zone correctly.

```
DateTimeUtil::time(DateTimeUtil::parse('05:30:15'));
```